# Apache Airflow - Slow to parse SQL queries on AWS MWAA

Tags: postgresql, airflow, mwaa

I'm trying to build a DAG on AWS MWAA, this DAG will export data from Postgres (RDS) to S3, but it's getting an issue once the MWAA tries to parse all queries from my task, in total it will export 385 tables, but the DAG gets stuck on running mode and does not start my task.

Basically, this process will:

1. Load the table schema
2. Rename Some Columns
3. Export data to S3

#### Function

```
def export_to_s3(dag, conn, db, pg_hook, export_date, s3_bucket, schemas):

    tasks = []
    run_queries = []
    
    for schema, features in schemas.items():
        t = features.get("tables")
        if t:
            tables = t
        else:
            tables = helper.get_tables(pg_hook, schema).table_name.tolist()

        is_full_export = features.get("full")

        for table in tables:
            columns = helper.get_table_schema(
                pg_hook, table, schema
            ).column_name.tolist()
            masked_columns = helper.masking_pii(columns, pii_columns=PII_COLS)
            masked_columns_str = ",\n".join(masked_columns)

            if is_full_export:
                statement = f'select {masked_columns_str} from {db}.{schema}."{table}"'
            else:
                statement = f'select {masked_columns_str} from {db}.{schema}."{table}" order by random() limit 10000'
            s3_bucket_key = export_date + "_" + schema + "_" + table + ".csv"
            sql_export = f"""
            SELECT * from aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
                '{statement}',
                    aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
                        '{s3_bucket}',
                        '{s3_bucket_key}',
                        'ap-southeast-2'),
                        options := 'FORMAT csv, DELIMITER $$|$$'
            )""".strip()
            run_queries.append(sql_export)



   def get_table_schema(pg_hook, table_name, table_schema):
        """ Gets the schema details of a given table in a given schema."""
        query = """
        SELECT column_name, data_type
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = '{0}'
          AND table_name = '{1}'
        order by ordinal_position
        """.format(table_schema, table_name)
    
        df_schema = pg_hook.get_pandas_df(query)
        return df_schema
    
    
    def get_tables(pg_hook, schema):
        query = """
        select table_name from information_schema.tables
        where table_schema = '{}' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name != '_sdc_rejected' """.format(schema)
    
        df_schema = pg_hook.get_pandas_df(query)
        return df_schema
```

#### Task

```
 task = PostgresOperator(
        sql=run_queries,
        postgres_conn_id=conn,
        task_id="export_to_s3",
        dag=dag,
        autocommit=True,
    )

    tasks.append(task)

    return tasks
```

#### Airflow list_dags output

```
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
mydag
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DagBag loading stats for /usr/local/airflow/dags
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of DAGs: 1
Total task number: 3
DagBag parsing time: 159.94030800000002
-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------
file                                                 | duration           | dag_num | task_num 
-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------
/mydag.py                                            | 159.05215199999998 |       1 |        3 
/ActivationPriorityCallList/CallList_Generator.py    | 0.878734           |       0 |        0 
/ActivationPriorityCallList/CallList_Preprocessor.py | 0.00744            |       0 |        0 
/ActivationPriorityCallList/CallList_Emailer.py      | 0.001154           |       0 |        0 
/airflow_helperfunctions.py                          | 0.000828           |       0 |        0 
-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------
```

#### Observation

If I enable only one table to be loaded in the task, it works well, but fails if all tables are enabled to be loaded.
This behavior is the same if execute Airflow from docker pointing out to RDS

#### Screenshot from the airflow list_dags:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved when I changed those values on MWAA.

- webserver.web_server_master_timeout
- webserver.web_server_worker_timeout

The default value is 30, I changed it to 480.

Link with documentation.

- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html

Comment: Doug, do you have your above code open-sourced? If so, i would love to take a look since I'm working on something very similar to mask my data